# Java for loop error

Tags: java

I am trying to get user input for sortValues[] array using the for statement (enter character 1, enter character 2, etc).

However, when I execute this, the program will not allow me to enter for character 2, instead skipping directly to character 3, as seen below.

[image]

How to resolve this? The code is included below.

thanks!

```
static public void s_1d_char () {
            int counter=0;
            int x=0;
            c.print("How many characters? ");
            counter = readInt();

            char[] sortValues = new char[counter+1];

            for (x=1;x<=counter;x++) {
                    System.out.println("Enter character "+(x)+":");
                sortValues[x] = readChar();
            }
    }
```

readChar implementation (this is from a library):

```
public synchronized char readChar ()
{
char result, ch;

if (ungotChar != EMPTY_BUFFER)
{
    result = (char) ungotChar;
    ungotChar = EMPTY_BUFFER;
    return (result);
}

if (lineBufferHead != lineBufferTail)
{
    result = lineBuffer [lineBufferTail];
    lineBufferTail = (lineBufferTail + 1) % lineBuffer.length;
    return (result);
}

startRow = currentRow;
startCol = currentCol;
if (currentRow > maxRow)
{
    startRow++;
    currentCol = 1;
}

// Turn cursor on if necessary
consoleCanvas.setCursorVisible (true);

// Wait for a character to be entered
while (true)
{
    ch = getChar ();

    if (ch == '\n')
    {
    clearToEOL = false;
    if (echoOn)
        print ("\n");
    clearToEOL = true;
    lineBuffer [lineBufferHead] = '\n';
    lineBufferHead = (lineBufferHead + 1) % lineBuffer.length;
    break;
    }
    if (ch == '\b')
    {
    if (lineBufferHead == lineBufferTail)
    {
        consoleCanvas.invertScreen ();
    }
    else
    {
        int chToErase;

        lineBufferHead = (lineBufferHead + lineBuffer.length - 1) % lineBuffer.length;
        chToErase = lineBuffer [lineBufferHead];
        if (echoOn)
        {
        if (chToErase != '\t')
        {
            erasePreviousChar ();
        }
        else
        {
            int cnt;
            eraseLineOfInput ();
            cnt = lineBufferTail;
            while (cnt != lineBufferHead)
            {
            print (lineBuffer [cnt]);
            cnt = (cnt + 1) % lineBuffer.length;
            }
        }
        }
    }
    } // if backspace
    else if (ch == '\025')
    {
    if (echoOn)
    {
        eraseLineOfInput ();
    }
    lineBufferHead = lineBufferTail;
    }
    else
    {
    if (echoOn)
    {
        print (ch);
    }
    lineBuffer [lineBufferHead] = ch;
    lineBufferHead = (lineBufferHead + 1) % lineBuffer.length;
    }
} // while

result = lineBuffer [lineBufferTail];
lineBufferTail = (lineBufferTail + 1) % lineBuffer.length;

// Turn cursor on if necessary
consoleCanvas.setCursorVisible (false);

return (result);
}
```

Comment: could it be that pressing enter counts as the second char?

Comment: If this is the case, how do I resolve it?

Comment: can you please write the implementation of `readChar()`?

Comment: I don't know if it is the case, which is why im' making comments and not answers, but you can check by just not pressing enter between chars

Comment: If you use a BufferedInputStream to wrap your input, you have a handy `readLine()` method.

Comment: Does this also skip the fourth character? If it does, the enter key is outputting a newline character.

Comment: Yes - it skips the fourth character and goes to fifth character, similar to image above

Comment: @01jayss: Then perhaps you should show the code for the `readChar()` method.

Comment: edited the question to include readChar() - it is from a library that we were instructed to use

Comment: @01jayss: Were you also instructed to read character-by-character?

Comment: @Doug Ramsey yes (if u mean Char 1: A, char 2: B, etc)

Comment: @01jayss: Then you are better off using a method besides `readChar()`. Consider something like the answer below.

Comment: @DougRamsey i try using sortValues[x] =System.console().readLine().charAt(0);, however now the program will not allow me to enter a character... Enter character 1 shows up, but it will not allow me to input anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend getting user input with a scanner:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

// ...
int counter = 0;

System.out.println("How many characters?");
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
counter = keyboard.nextInt();

char[] sortValues = new char[counter+1];

// Start your index variable off at 0
for (int x = 0; x < counter; x++) { 
  System.out.println("Enter character "+(x)+":");
  keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  String line = keyboard.nextLine();
  sortValues[x] = line.charAt(0);
}
```

This will capture the first character of the line. If the user enters more than one character, the program will read only the first.
Also, you should really start your index variable `x` off at 0, considering arrays are 0-based indexed.

Comment: thanks for your response. I have implemented your code, however, the program now stops after "How many characters" (it does not display Enter character, etc)...do you know the solution?

Comment: @01jayss: I updated the code snippet with a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

instead of `readChar()` try:

```
sortValues[x] = Integer.parseInt(System.console().readLine());
```

[How to read integer value from the standard input in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506077/how-to-read-integer-value-from-the-standard-input-in-java)

Comment: this only works for getting an integer... im trying to get a "char" value

Comment: @01jayss try maybe `char c=System.console().readLine().charAt(0)`

Comment: A char can be represented by an int. See [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). It's a 16-bit int, essentially, whereas the int data type is 32-bit.

Comment: @01jayss, what Roddy said, so long as you store it in a char (and maybe give it a cast), Java will automatically display it as a char.