# Is there an equivalent method to C's scanf in Java?

Tags: java

Java has the notion of [format strings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax), bearing a strong resemblance to [format strings in other languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string). It is used in JDK methods like [`String#format()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) for output conversion.

I was wondering if there's an input conversion method akin to [C's `scanf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) in Java?

Comment: juse behind you 
[a link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506077/how-to-read-integer-value-from-the-standard-input-in-java

Comment: Java have the `String.format(format, args)` (what It's pretty simmilar to printf) It's understandable that someone wants to know if there's a `scanf` equivalent. I don't know why this question is down voted.

Comment: There is 

`Scanner.next(Pattern pattern)`

which can be used with 

`Scanner.hasPattern(Pattern pattern)`

 for validation.

Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28java.util.regex.Pattern%29

This is a pertinent question, please reopen it people !

Comment: @AndrewG.H. I made a drastic edit and submitted for reopen. FWIW, I concur.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Take a look at [this site](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-input-from-console-java), it explains two methods for reading from console in java, using `Scanner` or the classical `InputStreamReader` from System.in.

Following code is taken from cited website:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class ReadConsoleSystem {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Enter something here : ");

    try{
        BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String s = bufferRead.readLine();

        System.out.println(s);
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
}
```

--

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadConsoleScanner {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

      System.out.println("Enter something here : ");

       String sWhatever;

       Scanner scanIn = new Scanner(System.in);
       sWhatever = scanIn.nextLine();

       scanIn.close();            
       System.out.println(sWhatever);
  }
}
```

Regards.

Comment: @Gopichand There isn't an exact match in java, but take a look at the `Scanner` doc, you can read specific type of data from stdin. For example: `int i = scanIn.nextInt();` for reading an int.

Comment: @Gopichand Sadly there's no exact method like scanf in java. The better approach that you could do is split a String and then take the tokens and cast them. If someone differs with me, then show me an example of `scanf("%d %d %s %f",a,b,c,d)`, one liner equivalent in java!

Answer (score 12):

There is not a pure scanf replacement in standard Java, but you could use a [java.util.Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) for the same problems you would use scanf to solve.

Answer (score 3):

Not an equivalent, but you can use a Scanner and a pattern to parse lines with three non-negative numbers separated by spaces, for example:

```
71 5796 2489
88 1136 5298
42 420 842
```

Here's the code using [`findAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#findAll(java.lang.String)):

```
new Scanner(System.in).findAll("(\\d+) (\\d+) (\\d+)")
        .forEach(result -> {
            int fst = Integer.parseInt(result.group(1));
            int snd = Integer.parseInt(result.group(2));
            int third = Integer.parseInt(result.group(3));
            int sum = fst + snd + third;
            System.out.printf("%d + %d + %d = %d", fst, snd, third, sum);
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

C/C++ has a notion of variable *references*, which makes creating something like `scanf` much easier. However, in Java, everything is passed by value. In the case of objects, their references are passed by value.

So, it's essentially impossible to have a concise equivalent to `scanf`. However, you can use `java.util.Scanner`, which does things similar to `scanf`.

So this C/C++:

```cpp
int a;
float b;

scanf("%d %f", &a, &b);
```

is (roughly) equivalent to this Java:

```java
int a;
float b;
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
  a = sc.nextInt();
  b = sc.nextFloat();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If one really wanted to they could make there own version of `scanf()` like so:

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class Testies {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();

    // get input
    System.out.println("Give me input:");
    scanf(strings, nums);

    System.out.println("Ints gathered:");
    // print numbers scanned in
    for(Integer num : nums){
        System.out.print(num + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("\nStrings gathered:");
    // print strings scanned in
    for(String str : strings){
        System.out.print(str + " ");
    }

    System.out.println("\nData:");
    for(int i=0; i<strings.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(nums.get(i) + " " + strings.get(i));
    }
}

// get line from system
public static void scanf(ArrayList<String> strings, ArrayList<Integer> nums){
    Scanner getLine = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner input = new Scanner(getLine.nextLine());

    while(input.hasNext()){
        // get integers
        if(input.hasNextInt()){
            nums.add(input.nextInt());
        }
        // get strings
        else if(input.hasNext()){
            strings.add(input.next());
        }
    }
}

// pass it a string for input
public static void scanf(String in, ArrayList<String> strings, ArrayList<Integer> nums){
    Scanner input = (new Scanner(in));

    while(input.hasNext()){
        // get integers
        if(input.hasNextInt()){
            nums.add(input.nextInt());
        }
        // get strings
        else if(input.hasNext()){
            strings.add(input.next());
        }
    }
}


}
```

Obviously my methods only check for Strings and Integers, if you want different data types to be processed add the appropriate arraylists and checks for them.  Also, `hasNext()` should probably be at the bottom of the `if-else if` sequence since `hasNext()` will return true for all of the data in the string.

Output:

`Give me input:
        apples 8 9 pears oranges 5
        Ints gathered:
        8 9 5 
        Strings gathered:
        apples pears oranges 
        Data:
        8 apples
        9 pears
        5 oranges`

Probably not the best example; but, the point is that `Scanner` implements the `Iterator` class.  Making it easy to iterate through the scanners input using the `hasNext<datatypehere>()` methods; and then storing the input.

Answer (score 0):

Java always takes arguments as a string type...(**String args[]**) so you need to convert in your desired type.

- Use `Integer.parseInt()` to convert your string into Interger.
- To print any string you can use `System.out.println()`

**Example :**

```
  int a;
  a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
```

and for **Standard Input** you can use codes like

```
  StdIn.readInt();
  StdIn.readString();
```

Comment: `StdIn` isn't a class in java.  I believe it's a class that the folks at Princeton wrote [link](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/StdIn.java).  However, it would work if you had that class in your project.  If you look at the code for `StdIn` they just use a `Scanner` to read all of the input.

Answer (score 0):

THERE'S an even simpler answer

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String myBeautifulScanf = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
        System.out.println( myBeautifulScanf );

    }
}
```

Comment: This is not simpler than the accepted answer, it is the same.

Comment: It's way less code, that makes it simpler. All the unimportant parts from the accepted answer were cleaned away