# Getting error while reading integer input

Tags: java

Input:

```
2
```

My program:

```
 public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        /*
         * Read input from stdin and provide input before running*/

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));


        String line = br.readLine();

        int cases = Integer.parseInt(line);}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2 "
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
```

How to solve this i want that the value of cases=2; what's wrong

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506077/how-to-read-integer-value-from-the-standard-input-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [trim](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) your string

```
int cases = Integer.parseInt(line.trim());}
```