# Displaying multiplication table based on user input

Tags: java, input

I'm working on iterations right now, as shown in this page of my textbook:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7vbm.jpg

I have worked out the following code:

```
package rectangle;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class messin {
public static void main(String[] args){
int number;



Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
number = scanner.nextInt();
double newstuff = Math.sqrt(number*number+number*number);

System.out.format("%10.3f%n", newstuff);
}

}
```

This is suppose to be a rectangle driver that uses the equation c = sqrt(a^2+b^2). As you can see I am not very far, but I will update as I get further. Thanks for the help and patients with the edits.

Comment: I believe this is what you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506077/how-to-read-integer-value-from-the-standard-input-in-java

Comment: Sorry, which numbers do you want?

Comment: I'm trying to create the image up above (the link). I suppose I should have just posted the code I have done thus far in that, which isn't much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Scanner from java.util package to get the input from user.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int num = scan.nextInt();


for (int i = 1; i < num; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%d\t", i);
}
System.out.println();
for (int i1 = 1; i1 < num; i1++) {
     for (int j = 1; j <= i1; j++) {
          System.out.printf("%d\t", i1 * j);
     }
     System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, I re-edited the question to be simple to understand what I am trying to do.

Comment: You can get two inputs for a and b and use `Math.sqrt(num1*2+num2*2);`