# Ordinals java - Java I class

Tags: java, prompt, ordinals

Stuck on getting the prompt to enter a number 1 to 10 - and results should add the st, rd, th, and nd to the number.
Write a program that prompts the user to enter any integer     from 1 to 10 and then displays the integer in ordinal form with suffix attached.

```
public class Ordinals {

    public static String Ordinals(int i) {

            System.out.println("Enter an integer between 0 to 10: ");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


            int hundred = value % 100;
            int tens = value % 10;
            if (hundred - tens == 10) {
                return "th";
            }
            switch (tens) {
            case 1:
                return "st";
            case 2:
                return "nd";
            case 3:
                return "rd";
            default:
                return "th";

            }


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Ordinals number = new Ordinals();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                String st = number.Ordinals(i);
                System.out.println(i + " = " + i + st);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: and your question is...?

Comment: Short Answer --> [value = input.nextInt()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506077/how-to-read-integer-value-from-the-standard-input-in-java);

Comment: Your prompt text is incorrect.

Comment: You don't need to use modulus either if valid values and between 1 and 10 inclusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion it would be better to move `Scanner` to main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Ordinals number = new Ordinals();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(true){
        System.out.println("Enter an integer between 0 to 10: ");
        int i = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println(i+number.Ordinals(i));
    }
}
```

and then add to Ordinals:

```
int value = i;
```

Method will be independent form input type.

Answer (score 1):

Add `value = input.nextInt()` under the line creating Scanner.