# Java user input to change board space of Tic-Tac-Toe with GUI

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, user-input, tic-tac-toe

I am having trouble figuring out how to get user input to change the rows and columns of my two player Tic-Tac-Toe game to an arbitrary size. Im not sure how to use the scanner class so that the user can input the desired size of the board space by inputting the number of rows and columns. The input should affect the GUI display

Here is the code

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 * Tic-Tac-Toe: Two-player Graphics version with Simple-OO
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TTTGraphics2P extends JFrame {
   // Named-constants for the game board
   public static final int ROWS = 3;  // ROWS by COLS cells
   public static final int COLS = 3;

   // Named-constants of the various dimensions used for graphics drawing
   public static final int CELL_SIZE = 100; // cell width and height (square)
   public static final int CANVAS_WIDTH = CELL_SIZE * COLS;  // the drawing canvas
   public static final int CANVAS_HEIGHT = CELL_SIZE * ROWS;
   public static final int GRID_WIDTH = 8;                   // Grid-line's width
   public static final int GRID_WIDHT_HALF = GRID_WIDTH / 2; // Grid-line's half-width
   // Symbols (cross/nought) are displayed inside a cell, with padding from border
   public static final int CELL_PADDING = CELL_SIZE / 6;
   public static final int SYMBOL_SIZE = CELL_SIZE - CELL_PADDING * 2; // width/height
   public static final int SYMBOL_STROKE_WIDTH = 8; // pen's stroke width

   // Use an enumeration (inner class) to represent the various states of the game
   public enum GameState {
      PLAYING, DRAW, CROSS_WON, NOUGHT_WON
   }
   private GameState currentState;  // the current game state

   // Use an enumeration (inner class) to represent the seeds and cell contents
   public enum Seed {
      EMPTY, CROSS, NOUGHT
   }
   private Seed currentPlayer;  // the current player

   private Seed[][] board   ; // Game board of ROWS-by-COLS cells
   private DrawCanvas canvas; // Drawing canvas (JPanel) for the game board
   private JLabel statusBar;  // Status Bar

   /** Constructor to setup the game and the GUI components */
   public TTTGraphics2P() {
      canvas = new DrawCanvas();  // Construct a drawing canvas (a JPanel)
      canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT));

      // The canvas (JPanel) fires a MouseEvent upon mouse-click
      canvas.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
         @Override
         public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {  // mouse-clicked handler
            int mouseX = e.getX();
            int mouseY = e.getY();
            // Get the row and column clicked
            int rowSelected = mouseY / CELL_SIZE;
            int colSelected = mouseX / CELL_SIZE;

            if (currentState == GameState.PLAYING) {
               if (rowSelected >= 0 && rowSelected < ROWS && colSelected >= 0
                     && colSelected < COLS && board[rowSelected][colSelected] == Seed.EMPTY) {
                  board[rowSelected][colSelected] = currentPlayer; // Make a move
                  updateGame(currentPlayer, rowSelected, colSelected); // update state
                  // Switch player
                  currentPlayer = (currentPlayer == Seed.CROSS) ? Seed.NOUGHT : Seed.CROSS;
               }
            } else {       // game over
               initGame(); // restart the game
            }
            // Refresh the drawing canvas
            repaint();  // Call-back paintComponent().
         }
      });

      // Setup the status bar (JLabel) to display status message
      statusBar = new JLabel("  ");
      statusBar.setFont(new Font(Font.DIALOG_INPUT, Font.BOLD, 15));
      statusBar.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2, 5, 4, 5));

      Container cp = getContentPane();
      cp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      cp.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      cp.add(statusBar, BorderLayout.PAGE_END); // same as SOUTH

      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      pack();  // pack all the components in this JFrame
      setTitle("Tic Tac Toe");
      setVisible(true);  // show this JFrame

      board = new Seed[ROWS][COLS]; // allocate array
      initGame(); // initialize the game board contents and game variables
   }

   /** Initialize the game-board contents and the status */
   public void initGame() {
      for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; ++row) {
         for (int col = 0; col < COLS; ++col) {
            board[row][col] = Seed.EMPTY; // all cells empty
         }
      }
      currentState = GameState.PLAYING; // ready to play
      currentPlayer = Seed.CROSS;       // cross plays first
   }

   /** Update the currentState after the player with "theSeed" has placed on
       (rowSelected, colSelected). */
   public void updateGame(Seed theSeed, int rowSelected, int colSelected) {
      if (hasWon(theSeed, rowSelected, colSelected)) {  // check for win
         currentState = (theSeed == Seed.CROSS) ? GameState.CROSS_WON : GameState.NOUGHT_WON;
      } else if (isDraw()) {  // check for draw
         currentState = GameState.DRAW;
      }
      // Otherwise, no change to current state (still GameState.PLAYING).
   }

   /** Return true if it is a draw (i.e., no more empty cell) */
   public boolean isDraw() {
      for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; ++row) {
         for (int col = 0; col < COLS; ++col) {
            if (board[row][col] == Seed.EMPTY) {
               return false; // an empty cell found, not draw, exit
            }
         }
      }
      return true;  // no more empty cell, it's a draw
   }

   /** Return true if the player with "theSeed" has won after placing at
       (rowSelected, colSelected) */
   public boolean hasWon(Seed theSeed, int rowSelected, int colSelected) {
      return (board[rowSelected][0] == theSeed  // 3-in-the-row
            && board[rowSelected][1] == theSeed
            && board[rowSelected][2] == theSeed
       || board[0][colSelected] == theSeed      // 3-in-the-column
            && board[1][colSelected] == theSeed
            && board[2][colSelected] == theSeed
       || rowSelected == colSelected            // 3-in-the-diagonal
            && board[0][0] == theSeed
            && board[1][1] == theSeed
            && board[2][2] == theSeed
       || rowSelected + colSelected == 2  // 3-in-the-opposite-diagonal
            && board[0][2] == theSeed
            && board[1][1] == theSeed
            && board[2][0] == theSeed);
   }

   /**
    *  Inner class DrawCanvas (extends JPanel) used for custom graphics drawing.
    */
   class DrawCanvas extends JPanel {
      @Override
      public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {  // invoke via repaint()
         super.paintComponent(g);    // fill background
         setBackground(Color.WHITE); // set its background color

         // Draw the grid-lines
         g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
         for (int row = 1; row < ROWS; ++row) {
            g.fillRoundRect(0, CELL_SIZE * row - GRID_WIDHT_HALF,
                  CANVAS_WIDTH-1, GRID_WIDTH, GRID_WIDTH, GRID_WIDTH);
         }
         for (int col = 1; col < COLS; ++col) {
            g.fillRoundRect(CELL_SIZE * col - GRID_WIDHT_HALF, 0,
                  GRID_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT-1, GRID_WIDTH, GRID_WIDTH);
         }

         // Draw the Seeds of all the cells if they are not empty
         // Use Graphics2D which allows us to set the pen's stroke
         Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
         g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(SYMBOL_STROKE_WIDTH, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND,
               BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND));  // Graphics2D only
         for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; ++row) {
            for (int col = 0; col < COLS; ++col) {
               int x1 = col * CELL_SIZE + CELL_PADDING;
               int y1 = row * CELL_SIZE + CELL_PADDING;
               if (board[row][col] == Seed.CROSS) {
                  g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
                  int x2 = (col + 1) * CELL_SIZE - CELL_PADDING;
                  int y2 = (row + 1) * CELL_SIZE - CELL_PADDING;
                  g2d.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
                  g2d.drawLine(x2, y1, x1, y2);
               } else if (board[row][col] == Seed.NOUGHT) {
                  g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                  g2d.drawOval(x1, y1, SYMBOL_SIZE, SYMBOL_SIZE);
               }
            }
         }

         // Print status-bar message
         if (currentState == GameState.PLAYING) {
            statusBar.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            if (currentPlayer == Seed.CROSS) {
               statusBar.setText("X's Turn");
            } else {
               statusBar.setText("O's Turn");
            }
         } else if (currentState == GameState.DRAW) {
            statusBar.setForeground(Color.RED);
            statusBar.setText("It's a Draw! Click to play again.");
         } else if (currentState == GameState.CROSS_WON) {
            statusBar.setForeground(Color.RED);
            statusBar.setText("'X' Won! Click to play again.");
         } else if (currentState == GameState.NOUGHT_WON) {
            statusBar.setForeground(Color.RED);
            statusBar.setText("'O' Won! Click to play again.");
         }
      }
   }

   /** The entry main() method */
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Input the number of rows");
     int userInputNumber = ROWS;

      // Run GUI codes in the Event-Dispatching thread for thread safety
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            new TTTGraphics2P(); // Let the constructor do the job
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you get rid of `Scanner`, make a previous window (something like a modal `JOptionPane`) where user configures the board with a `JTextField` and then display the board with the new configuration and have a `JMenu` or something like that, that calls this window again and repaint the board with this configuration again. Also as is, this question has a lot of code, try to post a [Runnable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which should be as minimum to compile and run but enough for us to see your issue or problem or what you have tried and want to achieve.

Comment: @Nate just a tip for you for future questions. This question has a huge amount of information that has nothing to do with your problem. You are really just asking how to read an integer from System.in which is a much simpler question than this looks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read integer value from the standard input in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506077/how-to-read-integer-value-from-the-standard-input-in-java)