# Array size and elements by user input

Tags: java, arrays

I want a program that asks first for the size of an array and next asks for the element. The size of the array is int and the stored values are double. Like this:

```
How many numbers? 5 // 5 is user input
Please type the numbers:
1,111
4
11,45
21
3
The numbers in reverse order are:
3.0 21.0 11.45 4.0 1.111
```

My problem is, how to ask for the size and for the elements? Thanks in advance!

Comment: System.in.read() is your friend

Comment: You can also take a look at the Scanner class..Though System.in.read() would also do just fine

Comment: Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int size=sc.nextInt();

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read integer value from the standard input in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506077/how-to-read-integer-value-from-the-standard-input-in-java)

Comment: On some systems `Console console = System.console();` is also supported and makes your life easier

Comment: I know the Scanner method. Like this:
Int a = sc.nextInt();
I can do with arrays the same way??
Int [] arrayNumbers = sc.nextInt();

Comment: @TiborTóth If you know how to input an integer then you can use it to get the size of the array. Then initialise an array of that size. Then loop "size" number of times and in each iteration again input an integer and set at the corresponding array index.(This is using scanner class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
int arraysize=sc.nextInt();
double[] doubleArray = new double[arraysize];

for(int i=0; i<arraysize; i++){
doubleArray[i] = sc.nextDouble();
```

}