# How to accept arguments in java from the user

Tags: java

I'm trying to have the user input 2 strings into this function so that they can be compared.

I am not too familiar with java more familiar with c++ and I'm not a dev.

```
public class Levenshtein {

    public static int distance(String a, String b) {
        a = a.toLowerCase();
        b = b.toLowerCase();
        // i == 0
        int [] costs = new int [b.length() + 1];
        for (int j = 0; j < costs.length; j++)
            costs[j] = j;
        for (int i = 1; i <= a.length(); i++) {
            // j == 0; nw = lev(i -1, j)
            costs[0] = i;
            int nw = i - 1;
            for (int j = 1; j <= b.length(); j++) {
                int cj = Math.min(1 + Math.min(costs[j], costs[j - 1]), a.charAt(i - 1) == b.charAt(j - 1) ? nw : nw + 1);
                nw = costs[j];
                costs[j] = cj;
            }
        }
        return costs[b.length()];
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        String [] data = { "kitten", "Mitten" };
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i += 2)
            System.out.println("distance(" + data[i] + ", " + data[i+1] + ") = " + distance(data[i], data[i+1]));
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506077/how-to-read-integer-value-from-the-standard-input-in-java), and maybe [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871520/how-can-i-read-input-from-the-console-using-the-scanner-class-in-java).

Comment: @Avi Nice catch. Side note: don't forget that you have enough reputation to flag questions as duplicates as well, so that people can vote on it in the close vote queue.

Comment: I was feeling nice enough to answer it today instead of flagging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use the `args` in main

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i += 2)
        System.out.println("distance(" + args[i] + ", " + args[i+1] + ") = " + distance(args[i], args[i+1]));
}
```

and run it with `java -jar app.jar kitten mitten`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how to use [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to read inputs in Java.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
String first = s.nextLine();
String second = s.nextLine();
String[] nextTwo = s.nextLine().split(" ");
System.out.println(first);
System.out.println(second);
System.out.println(nextTwo[0]);
System.out.println(nextTwo[1]);
s.close();
```

**Sample input**

> I am a teapot
>   Short and stout
>   Here is my handle

**Sample output**

> I am a teapot
>   Short and stout
>   Here
>   is

As for how to apply this in your program, simply do the following:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    // Using this construct, the "try-with-resources" block, will automatically
    // close the Scanner resource for you
    try(Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in) {
        System.out.println("Enter first word:");
        String first = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter second word:");
        String second = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println(String.format("The distance is: %d",distance(first, second)));
    }//Scanner s is automatically closed here
}
```

Note that you should generally NOT close the `System.in` stream, as it will disallow you from reading input in the rest of the program. However, as your program terminates in the scope of the try-with-resources block, it is acceptable to do so in this scenario.
One approach you can take to close Scanners linked to your `System.in` stream is to wrap `System.in` in a `CloseShieldInputStream`, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14143048/5699679).

Comment: As I noted to IlikeSahne you should not close the `System.in` stream or you will cause issues if you attempt to use it again.  This includes using it with `try-with resources`.  If one attempts to use `Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in); s.nextLine()` later in the program you will get an exception and be unable to read a line (because you are unable to ever open it again)

Comment: If you want to see this easily just try throwing your code into a method and call the method twice and you will see that code fails.

Comment: @Nexevis I agree absolutely; I have added a note of caution :)

Comment: Nevermind I thought you only added the `CloseShieldInputStream` part, I think your warning is fine.

Comment: @Nexevis That is assuming you know that you're dealing with the `System.in` stream. You may be dealing with arbitrary input streams, in which case you will need to close your Scanners after creation. `CloseShieldInputStream` is one such method to keep your Scanners stream type agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the scanner object:

```
Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);  // Create a Scanner object
System.out.println("Enter username");

String userName = myObj.nextLine();  // Read user input
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Scanner for inputs from the Console.

U can do:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String s1 = sc.nextLine();
String s2 = sx.nextLine();
System.out.println("distance(" + s1 + ", " + s2 + ") = " + distance(s1, s2));
sc.close();
```

Comment: Besides the typo of `sx` note that you also should not close the `System.in` stream.

Comment: Why should I not close it?

Comment: 1) Because it cannot be reopened. 2) Because you don't need to close it.

Comment: @ILikeSahne Here is some [info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142853/close-a-scanner-linked-to-system-in) on it.  Basically you close `System.in` along with the scanner doing this.  For example you would be unable to open a new `Scanner` for the rest of the program execution using `System.in` since you closed it.

Comment: Oh ty, I didn't know that. A few programs of me had this problem and I couldn't fix it.