# Using user input from a scanner multiple times?

Tags: java

I am trying to use a user-entered number from the scanner in my code in multiple places. Below the line should be the same user-entered number as the first. Is this possible?

```
Scanner inputHere = new Scanner(system.in);
System.out.println("Please select me");
String inputHereOne = inputHere.nextLine();
System.out.println("----------------------------------");
```

Comment: Yes,it's possible.

Comment: You just want to use `inputHereOne` multiple times?

Comment: Do not forget to close your `Scanner`.

Comment: A stdin scanner does not necessarily need to be closed afaik.

Comment: @Carcigenicate is right, although in certain (rare and usually problematic) circumstances you might find yourself needing to do so.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I am attempting to use the user-entered number from that scanner multiple places below the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Use the value stored in `inputHereOne`. No need to call `inputHere.nextLine()` until you actually need the next line of input. Like so:

```
System.out.println(inputHereOne);
System.out.println(inputHereOne);
```

This will print `inputHereOne`, twice.

Comment: @user9424843 That code will (line 1) create a Scanner reading from System input, (2) print "Please select me", (3) create a String variable `inputHereOne` with value equals to the next line from System input, and (4) print lots of dashes. After that code has run, you can use the value read into `inputHereOne` as you would like, by simply referring to `inputHereOne`. For example, to parse the `int` value out of `inputHereOne`, you might say something like `int inputValue = Integer.parseInt(inputHereOne);`. From then on, you could refer to the value as an int by referring to `inputValue`.

Comment: @user9424843 Please do some research. There are plenty of resources available on the [site](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2506146/5699679) and Google to figure out how to do simple input reading.