# Java.util.scanner error handling

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm helping a friend with a java problem. However, we've hit a snag. We're using Java.Util.Scanner.nextInt() to get a number from the user, asking continiously if the user gives anything else. Only problem is, we can't figure out how to do the error handeling.

What we've tried:

```
do {
  int reloop = 0;
  try {
    number = nextInt(); 
  } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println ("Please enter a number!");
    reloop ++; 
  }
} while(reloop != 0);
```

Only problem is, this loops indefinatly if you enter in something not a number.

Any help?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [`hasNextInt()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29) to verify that the `Scanner` will succeed if you do a `nextInt()`. You can also call and discard `nextLine()` if you want to skip the "garbage".

So, something like this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
while (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
   System.out.println("int, please!");
   sc.nextLine();
}
int num = sc.nextInt();
System.out.println("Thank you! (" + num + ")");
```

#### See also:

- [How do I keep a scanner from throwing exceptions when the wrong type is entered? (java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496239/how-do-i-keep-a-scanner-from-throwing-exceptions-when-the-wrong-type-is-entered/2496812#2496812)

---

The problem with your code, in addition to the unnecessarily verbose error handling because you let `nextInt()` throw an `InputMismatchException` instead of checking for `hasNextInt()`, is that when it *does* throw an exception, you don't advance the `Scanner` past the problematic input! That's why you get an infinite loop!

You can call and discard the `nextLine()` to fix this, but even better is if you use the exception-free `hasNextInt()` pre-check technique presented above instead.

Answer (score 2):

if the number is non-int , exception will pop, if not reloop will become 1 , and loop will exit

```
  int reloop = 0;
  do {
   try {
        number = nextInt();
        reloop ++; 
  } catch (Exception e) {
       System.out.println ("Please enter a number!");
  }}
 while(reloop == 0);
```

Comment: I would use a `boolean` instead of an int.

Comment: That will loop forever if the next token is not an `int`