# if i entered numbers separated with commas, how could i extract the numbers?

Tags: java

for example....

26, 15, 37

how could i get the numbers from a Scanner , ( lets say for instance i want to add or subtract,,,?)

Comment: What are you entering the numbers into?  Show us the code if you have it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [String.split()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29).

If you want to use the `Scanner` API:

```
private static final Pattern COMMA_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\s*,\\s*");

public List<Integer> getIntegerList() {
    // Assumes scanner is positioned at first integer in list.
    List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (;;) {
        integers.add(scanner.nextInt());
        if (scanner.hasNext(COMMA_PATTERN)) {
            // Read and discard comma token, and continue parsing list.
            scanner.next();
        } else {
            // Number is not followed by comma, stop parsing.
            break;
        }
    }
    return integers;
}
```

More error handling is needed, but hopefully, this example illustrates the approach.

You can also use `Scanner.useDelimiter()`:

```
private static final Pattern COMMA_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\s*,\\s*");

public List<Integer> getIntegerList() {
    // Assumes scanner is positioned at first integer in list.
    List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Pattern oldDelimiter = scanner.delimiter();
    scanner.useDelimiter(COMMA_PATTERN);
    while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        integers.add(scanner.nextInt());
    }
    // Reset delimiter
    scanner.useDelimiter(oldDelimiter);
    return integers;
}
```

Comment: im using

  Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter(", *");


        
        System.out.print("Enter student record : ");
        String name = input1.next();
        
        System.out.println(input1);

Comment: its only giving me the first number

Comment: for example 45, 46, 67 ... out put 45

Comment: @WM: If you set the delimiter, you do not need to extract commas as tokens. I updated my answer with a code sampling using `useDelimiter`. Also, my first code sample didn't allow whitespace surrounding the commas; the updated version does, by changing the pattern to "\\s*,\\s*".

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Scanner.useDelimiter`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter%28java.lang.String%29). It actually takes regex, so you'd want to learn some basics.

```
    String text = "1 , 2 3,      4,5";
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(text).useDelimiter("\\s*,?\\s*");
    while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println(sc.nextInt());
    } // prints "1", "2", "3", "4","5"
```

#### See also

- http://www.regular-expressions.info/ -- the best tutorial resource

#### Related questions

- [How do I keep a scanner from throwing exceptions when the wrong type is entered? (java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496239/how-do-i-keep-a-scanner-from-throwing-exceptions-when-the-wrong-type-is-entered)

  - Using `hasNextInt()` to prevent exception is much better than `Integer.parseInt` and `catch NumberFormatException`

Answer (score 2):

String.split() is OK, but [StringTokenizer](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) works everywhere and in every version of Java.

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("26, 15, 37", ", ");
int sum = 0;
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
    sum += Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
}
```

Comment: I also believe this is faster

Comment: `StringTokenizer` is legacy class, much better replacement exists now, e.g. `Scanner`.

Answer (score 2):

Try to set a delimiter for your scanner object:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter(", *");
int first = s.nextInt();
int second = s.nextInt();
...
```

More examples can be found in [Scanner documentation](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

Answer (score 0):

Look at [useDelimiter](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter%28java.util.regex.Pattern%29).  You need a regex that will match either whitespace or commas.