# Runtime casting from String to other datatype

Tags: java

Hi I have Map of String values.

I want to cast this value at runtime.

e.g.

```
Map map = new HashMap();
map.put("key1","101");
map.put("key2","45.40");
```

Now runtime I know key1 is integer and key2 is double
How can I cast this.

I tried this:

```
("101").getClass().cast(Integer).
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////
e.g. ...........

String integerClass = "java.lang.Integer"; 
String strNum = "5"; 
Now How will you convert this strNum value "5" to Integer using integerClass.

.....Without using new Integer(strNum) directly

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You can't linguistically cast a `String` (a reference type) to an `int` or a `double` (a primitive numeric type). You'd have to convert them. Thankfully, there are standard methods to do them for you:

#### API links

- [`int Integer.parseInt(String)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29)
- [`double Double.parseDouble(String)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29)
- [`NumberFormatException`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) -- this may be thrown by the `parseXXX`

#### Note

[`T Class<T>.cast(Object)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast%28java.lang.Object%29) does something entirely different. It has to do with generics, reflection, type-tokens, etc.

---

That said, I noticed that you used a raw `Map` type. Since this looks like a new code, it should be said that you should NOT use raw types in new code. It's possible that you may never need to convert from `String` to `int`/`double` in the first place (or at least do it **BEFORE** you put them into the map).

A `Map<String,Number>` (or perhaps a `Map<String,Double>`) would be better, because the map is "type-safe"; you know it maps `String` to `Number`, and the compiler would ensure that you're not doing anything to violate this type invariant.

#### Related questions

- [What is a raw type and why shouldn’t we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

---

Based on OP's comments, it looks like something like this was desired:

```
import java.util.*;
public class MapTranslate {
    static Object interpret(String s) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(s);
        return
            sc.hasNextInt() ? sc.nextInt() :
            sc.hasNextLong() ? sc.nextLong() :
            sc.hasNextDouble() ? sc.nextDouble() :
            sc.hasNext() ? sc.next() :
            s;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String,String> map1 = new HashMap<String,String>();
        map1.put("One", "1");
        map1.put("PI", "3.141592653589793");
        map1.put("10^12", "1000000000000");
        map1.put("Infinity", "oo");
        map1.put("Blank", "   ");

        Map<String,Object> map2 = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : map1.entrySet()) {
            map2.put(entry.getKey(), interpret(entry.getValue()));
        }

        for (Map.Entry<String,Object> entry: map2.entrySet()) {
            System.out.format("%s->[%s] (%s)%n",
                entry.getKey(),
                entry.getValue(),
                entry.getValue().getClass().getSimpleName()
            );
        }
    }
}
```

This produces:

```
PI->[3.141592653589793] (Double)
Infinity->[oo] (String)
One->[1] (Integer)
10^12->[1000000000000] (Long)
Blank->[   ] (String)
```

This is not the most robust (e.g. it doesn't handle `null` keys/values), but it may be a good starting point. Note that it uses [`java.util.Scanner`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) and its `hasXXX` methods; this way you don't have to worry about any `NumberFormatException`.

Without understanding the big picture, though, it's hard to comment whether something like this is even a good idea to begin with.

#### Related questions

- [How do I keep a scanner from throwing exceptions when the wrong type is entered? (java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496239/how-do-i-keep-a-scanner-from-throwing-exceptions-when-the-wrong-type-is-entered)

---

#### Using reflection

This seems to also be an aspect of the question; the following should be instructive:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class ValueOfString {
    static <T> T valueOf(Class<T> klazz, String arg) {
        Exception cause = null;
        T ret = null;
        try {
            ret = klazz.cast(
                klazz.getDeclaredMethod("valueOf", String.class)
                .invoke(null, arg)
            );
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            cause = e;
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            cause = e;
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            cause = e;
        }
        if (cause == null) {
            return ret;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(cause);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Integer ii = valueOf(Integer.class, "42"); // no need to cast!
        System.out.println(ii); // prints "42"

        Object o = valueOf(Class.forName("java.lang.Double"), "3.14159");
        System.out.println(o);
        System.out.println(o instanceof Double); // prints "true"       
    }
}
```

The above snippet uses type tokens and reflections to invoke `static valueOf(String)` method. The use of reflection may not be justifiable in this case, however, and it may simply be better to just explicitly check what the desired conversion is, e.g. `"java.lang.Integer"`, and then invoke `Integer.valueOf` accordingly.

Comment: I don't want to cast to any primitive datatype.

Comment: @Gengrlin: see latest revision and tell me if it helps.

Comment: @Gengrlin: also, `int` and `double` are primitive datatypes, and your original question seemed to indicate that this _conversion_ is what you wanted to do. Please clarify your intention; I will do everything I can to help.

Comment: Thanks This is closest solution but.... Here is what I want to do......
I am storing datatype of parameters in db and i am getting values from client side in string so now runtime I want to convert this string values to required datatype.
//////////////// example .. String integerClass = "java.lang.Integer"; String strNum = "5"; ............. Now How will you convert this strNum value "5" to Integer using integerClass. .....Without using new Integer(strNum) directly

Comment: @Gengrlin: what other types are there besides `java.lang.Integer`?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and solved it using the GenericValidator Helper Class from the Apache Commons Project to find out what Datatype I assume could be in the string and then parse it.

```
public Object parseString(String myString) {

        if (GenericValidator.isLong(myString)) {
            return Long.parseLong(myString);
        } else if (GenericValidator.isDouble(myString)) {
            return Double.parseDouble(myString);
        } else if (GenericValidator.isDate(myString, Locale.GERMAN)) {
            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("DD.MM.YYYY");
            return  LocalDate.parse(myString, formatter);
        } else {
            return myString;
        }
}
```

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the string into a double, like this:

```
double d = Double.parseDouble("45.40");
```

Comment: Let me explain you in details.......
My situation is: 

I have two map at RunTime:::
1st Map: key and valueClass.......
2nd Map: key and value (value in string)
..........
Now Runtime I want to cast string values of 2nd map 
as per required 1st map ValueClass can be any datatype (Integer, String,Double, Long etc)

Comment: You're misusing the word runtime.  I have no idea what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

the `cast` method on `Object` will do an `instanceof` test, and as you probably know, will throw a `ClassCastException` in this case.  What you can do is the use the constructors for `Double` and `Integer` that take `String` arguements.

Comment: Okay here is one another sample.
String integerClass = "java.lang.Integer";
String strNum = "5";
.............
Now How will you convert this strNum value "5" to Integer using integerClass.
.....Without using new Integer(strNum) directly

Comment: That would be useless, because you can't do anything with it unless you know the type at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Integer.parseInt](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) and [Double.parseDouble](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String))

```
int value1 = Integer.parseInt(map.get("key1"));
double value2 = Double.parseDouble(map.get("key2"));
```

Comment: Its not that simple. Its runtime so I am getting on Class of any datatype and based on datatype received value must be converted

Answer (score 0):

You cannot **cast** a `String` to any other type, you must **convert** it. For example, to convert to an `Integer`:

```
Integer value = Integer.valueOf(string);
```

For `Double`:

```
Double value = Double.valueOf(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, after reading the additional comments, I think you are after something like this:

```
static Number convertNumber(String className, String value)
  throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, 
    IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {
  Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
  Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("valueOf", String.class);
  return (Number)method.invoke(clazz, value);
}
```

Which you could use like this:

```
Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
map1.put("key1", "java.lang.Integer");
map2.put("key1","101");
map1.put("key2", "java.lang.Double");
map2.put("key2","45.40");

try {
  Number value;
  value = convertNumber(map1.get("key1"), map2.get("key1"));
  System.out.format("Value = %s, type = %s\n", value, value.getClass().getSimpleName());
  value = convertNumber(map1.get("key2"), map2.get("key2"));
  System.out.format("Value = %s, type = %s\n", value, value.getClass().getSimpleName());
  value = convertNumber("java.lang.Integer", "foo!");
  System.out.format("Value = %s, type = %s\n", value, value.getClass().getSimpleName());
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace(System.out);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, I think you could use Java Reflection to create new objects. Invoking the Constructor is equivalent to creating new objects.

> `Map<Integer, String> typeMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();`
>
> `Map<Integer, String> valueMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();`
>
> `typeMap.put(1, "java.lang.Double");`
>
> `valueMap.put(1, "10");`
>
> `Class clazz = Class.forName((String) typeMap.get(1));`
>
> `Constructor constructor = clazz.getConstructor(String.class);`
>
> `Object obj = constructor.newInstance(valueMap.get(1));`