# How to use Scanner to accept only valid int as input

Tags: java, validation, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to make a small program more robust and I need some help with that.

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
int num1;
int num2 = 0;

System.out.print("Enter number 1: ");
num1 = kb.nextInt();

while(num2 < num1) {
    System.out.print("Enter number 2: ");
    num2 = kb.nextInt();
}
```

1. Number 2 has to be greater than number 1
2. Also I want the program to automatically check and ignore if the user enters a character instead of a number. Because right now when a user enters for example `r` instead of a number the program just exits.

Comment: Of what type is 'kb'? Usually, when reading from stdin (System.in), you get the ascii/UTF8-Code for every single character, making the check you want very easy. But that seems to be hidden in the object behind the 'kb' reference. No one can provide a working code at this point!

Comment: would kb be `new Scanner(System.in)` by any chance?

Comment: static Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use [`Scanner.hasNextInt()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29):

> Returns `true` if the next token in this scanner's input can be interpreted as an `int` value in the default radix using the `nextInt()` method. The scanner does not advance past any input.

Here's a snippet to illustrate:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter number 1: ");
while (!sc.hasNextInt()) sc.next();
int num1 = sc.nextInt();
int num2;
System.out.print("Enter number 2: ");
do {
    while (!sc.hasNextInt()) sc.next();
    num2 = sc.nextInt();
} while (num2 < num1);
System.out.println(num1 + " " + num2);
```

You don't have to `parseInt` or worry about `NumberFormatException`. Note that since the `hasNextXXX` methods don't advance past any input, you may have to call `next()` if you want to skip past the "garbage", as shown above.

#### Related questions

- [How do I keep a scanner from throwing exceptions when the wrong type is entered? (java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496239/how-do-i-keep-a-scanner-from-throwing-exceptions-when-the-wrong-type-is-entered)

Comment: You can use other data types like Double reference type. For intance:   "scanner.hasNextDouble()"

Answer (score 4):

1. the condition num2 < num1 should be num2 <= num1 if num2 has to be greater than num1
2. not knowing what the kb object is, I'd read a `String` and then `try`ing `Integer.parseInt()` and if you don't `catch` an exception then it's a number, if you do, read a new one, maybe by setting num2 to Integer.MIN_VALUE and using the same type of logic in your example.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String... args) throws Throwable {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        int num1;
        System.out.print("Enter number 1: ");
        while (true)
            try {
                num1 = Integer.parseInt(kb.nextLine());
                break;
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                System.out.print("Try again: ");
            }

        int num2;
        do {
            System.out.print("Enter number 2: ");
            while (true)
                try {
                    num2 = Integer.parseInt(kb.nextLine());
                    break;
                } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                    System.out.print("Try again: ");
                }
        } while (num2 < num1);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\d+$");
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num1;
        int num2 = 0;
        String temp;
        Matcher numberMatcher;
        System.out.print("Enter number 1: ");
        try
        {
            num1 = kb.nextInt();
        }

        catch (java.util.InputMismatchException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Input");
            //
            return;
        }
        while(num2<num1)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter number 2: ");
            temp = kb.next();
            numberMatcher = p.matcher(temp);
            if (numberMatcher.matches())
            {
                num2 = Integer.parseInt(temp);
            }

            else
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid Number");
            }
        }
    }
```

You could try to parse the string into an `int` as well, but usually people try to avoid throwing exceptions.

What I have done is that I have defined a regular expression that defines a number, `\d` means a numeric digit. The `+` sign means that there has to be one or more numeric digits. The extra `\` in front of the `\d` is because in java, the `\` is a special character, so it has to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

I see that Character.isDigit perfectly suits the need, since the input will be just one symbol.
Of course we don't have any info about this kb object but just in case it's a java.util.Scanner instance, I'd also suggest using java.io.InputStreamReader for command line input. Here's an example:

```
java.io.BufferedReader reader = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(System.in));
try {
  reader.read();
}
catch(Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
reader.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is also to take the next token as a String, [converts this string to a char array](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29) and test that [each character in the array is a digit](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit%28char%29).

I think that's correct, if you don't want to deal with the exceptions.