# How to handle wrong user input

Tags: java

My program requires user to enter a 4-digit number(int type). Currently, when the user enters any character other than numeric, the program crashes. My hope is that when the user enters a non-numeric character, the program can tell the user "Wrong input" then let the user re-enter.

Does exception handling work for this? Or is there any other good way to solve this?

Comment: See the documentation

Comment: Your application is already throwing an error when it's crashing. what you need to do is catch the exception, and handle it (print appropriate message to user etc.)

Comment: see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using scanner, you can use the `nextInt()` method with the condition `hasNextInt()` which would only read integer inputs. Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912817/how-to-use-scanner-to-accept-only-valid-int-as-input) for example:

Taken from the above mentioned post.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter number 1: ");
while (!sc.hasNextInt()) sc.next();
int num1 = sc.nextInt();
int num2;
System.out.print("Enter number 2: ");
do {
    while (!sc.hasNextInt()) sc.next();
    num2 = sc.nextInt();
} while (num2 < num1);
System.out.println(num1 + " " + num2);
```

Also you can look at the documentation for scanner's `nextInt()` [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29)