# Avoiding nested try/catch

Tags: java, exception, nested, try-catch

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = input.next();
    int a;
    try{
        try{
            a = Integer.parseInt(str);
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
            throw new CustomException("message");
        }
        if (a>50) throw new CustomException("message");
    }
    catch(CustomException e){
        //do something
    }
}
}
```

If `str` is something other than numbers, `parseInt` will throw a `NumberFormatException`. But I want to 'convert' it so that I'll have a `CustomException` with "message" instead. Can I do this without using a nested `try/catch` blocks like above?

Comment: Is this your exact use case? If so then what you want to do isn't necessary and you can just catch the NumberFormatException.

Comment: `if (a>50) throw new CustomException("message")`??

Comment: What is your intend? Smells like a [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). And maybe you can replace the `CustomException` with an [`IllegalArgumentException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html).

Comment: Have a look at "exception chaining" before proceeding much further. The answers at the time of my writing this are rubbish.

Comment: @Turing85 err...yeah maybe...but i just wanted to know whether i can rethrow an exception in the catch block and handle the rethrown exception within the method without using a nested try/catch block.

Answer (score 2):

you could refator your example to

```
 try {
     a = Integer.parseInt(str);
     if (a > 50) {
         throw new CustomException("message");
     }
 } catch (NumberFormatException | CustomException e){
     //do something
 }
```

Comment: Your first example doesn't behave the same way as his. You throw a `CustomException` from inside the catch which won't be caught.

Comment: when i call System.out.println(e.getMessage()); inside the catch block, a NumberFormatException e will give "For input string: ~~" instead of "message".

Comment: @tareviverat is it relevant as in both cases you have same message?

Comment: yep, and i'm required to handle with a single method all exceptions thrown, so i need to rethrow a CustomException in the catch block.

Comment: @tareviverat you don't have to rethrow exception, you could wrap everything in function, and handle exception in shared block in place where you call function

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Scanner.hasNextInt()` to parse the int without worrying about exceptions.

see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912817/how-to-use-scanner-to-accept-only-valid-int-as-input) for detailed code.

Answer (score 0):

You could write:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = input.next();
    int a;
    try{
        a = Integer.parseInt(str);
        if (a>50) throw new NumberFormatException("message");
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e){
        //do something
    }
}
```

but I suggest you to use your version, since the code is more readable. My version, even if removes the inner try, is less readable than yours.