# How can I make a specific Java output with *?

Tags: java, for-loop

How can I make this output in Java in a for-loop? How can I make every line less "*" ?

```
Input:
enter number: 6
```

Java output:

```
******
*****
****
***
**
*
```

Comment: with two nested loops while the inner loop decreases the time it loops by one after each outer iteration.

Comment: This looks suspiciously like a homework problem! I recommend you take a look at some documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: this can easily be done, even without nested loops. but it does take some effort

Comment: Use two nested for loops with valid range and print '*' using System.out.println('*');

Comment: Please show us, what did you try and what was the result.

Comment: this output in a for loop: `for (;;) { System.out.println("******\n*****\n****\n***\n**\n*"); break; }`

Comment: @RobQuist meant to show what the question is missing :)

Comment: Lol. Hard to read sarcasm. Sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems a homework assignment, and [it's nice to you to achieve this little goals to correct programming learning](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems). As we're not here to make your homework, here you have few steps to guide you through:

- Define a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to ask [user's input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912817/how-to-use-scanner-to-accept-only-valid-int-as-input)
- Use [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to put user's input into a variable
- Use this variable in a inverted for-loop (with `loopCounter--`)

  ```
  for (int loopCounter = userInputVariable; loopCounter > 0; loopCounter --)
  ```
- To repeat the `*` use:

  - StringUtils `String repeated = StringUtils.repeat("*", loopCounter);` or
  - for loop to repeat the char

    ```
    for (int innerLoopCounter = 0; innerLoopCounter < loopCounter; innerLoopCounter ++)
    ```

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly!

Comment: glad to help @Michael, please, dont miss the link at the begining of my answer, it will make you understand better what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this. Please bear in mind that I don't know java.

```
for (int i = input; i > 0; i--) {
    System.out.println(StringUtils.repeat("*", i));
}
```