# How to check for user input without exiting for error

Tags: java, validation, input

I need to check the user input and ask for a correct one if the value is not a digit. However when I do this code, the program displays an error message and then crashes- it does not ask the user to give a new input. How can that be fixed? Thank you!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;
public class CentimeterInch
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        final int MAX=100, feet=12, meter=100;
        final double inch=2.54;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println ("This program converts distances. ");
        System.out.println ("Enter distance and unit (e.g. 37 1 or 100 2):");
        double distance=scan.nextDouble();
        if (!scan.hasNextDouble())
            {
                System.out.println ("please enter a numeric value");
                distance=scan.nextDouble();
            }
        int unitType = scan.nextInt();
        if (distance<0)
            {
                System.out.println ("Please enter a non negative distance");
            }
....
```

Comment: Helpful (duplicate?)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912817/how-to-use-scanner-to-accept-only-valid-int-as-input

Answer (score 1):

Just bring the if clause before performing `scan.nextDouble()`.

```
 if (!scan.hasNextDouble())
 {
   System.out.println ("please enter a numeric value");
   scan.nextLine();
   distance=scan.nextDouble();
 }

double distance=scan.nextDouble();
```

First make sure that the number to be read is a double value, then read it. You were doing the reverse

**What is `scan.nextLine()` doing here?**

Suppose the user enters `abc 2`. `scan.hasNextDouble()` checks wether the token to be read next is a double value or not. It's not, so `scan.hasNextDouble()` evaluates to `false` and the if clause gets executed. Inside the if clause, you have `scan.nextLine()`. It simply discards the current input from `scan`, thus flushing `scan`. If you don't do so, then `scan` still contains `abc 2` and upon executing `distance = scan.nextDouble()`, the compiler issues an error.

It's better if you replace `if` with `while`. Suppose user gives wrong input. Your program checks the input and finds out that it's not a double value. The `if` clause if executed and the user is asked to enter a numeric value. What if the user again enters a wrong input. This time, you will get an error. Using a while loop makes your program to keep asking the user for a correct input until he enters a numeric value.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer. I can't use while due to university restrictions at this stage, so IF is ok. Regarding the input check, I still don't get it. I'm still getting an error when I do it the way you wrote, and as far as I understand it, the bad input is still being placed into distance. I'm looking for something like Isdigit in c++ that you can put on the input before its placed into the variable