# Unable to use scanner in a method

Tags: java

I have a code which I would like to have three variables call on a method that reads user input and determine if it is an integer(if not reprompt the user), then return the input to the variable.  I get the following compiler error when I try to compile:

> Error: The method getInt(int) in the type Methods is not applicable for the arguments (java.util.Scanner)

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Methods{   
   public static void main(String [] arg){  

 Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);

 int a,b,c;  

 System.out.println("Enter three ints");  

 a = getInt(scan.nextInt());  
 b = getInt(scan.nextInt());  
 c = getInt(scan.nextInt());

   }



   public static int getInt(String input){ 
  Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);

  int num = 0;
    while (num <1) {
     if(scan.hasNextInt()) {
    int number = scan.nextInt();
    num +=1;
     }
     else{
       System.out.println("Invalid input.  Please enter an integer value."); 
       input.next();
     }

} 
 }
```

Any help you could give would be appreciated!

Comment: Your method `getInt` takes an `int` variable as its parameter. You cannot pass a `Scanner` instance where an `int` is expected. Also, your code doesn't compile as given... you're redefining `input` (a parameter of type` int` to the function `getInt`) inside the function `getInt` to be of type `Scanner`.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to read "use Scanner to accept only valid int as input"
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2913026/5980046

Comment: how would i use this answer in my method though?  i do think i understand how to accept integers only with scanner, but i dont know whats going wrong with calling on the method itself

Comment: You just put the code in  main,just compile and run. I assume you created Java console program.

Answer (score 0):

Your method `getInt(int input)` is expecting an integer as the argument.

But in your codes, you are providing a Scanner object instead of int:

```
a = getInt(scan);  
b = getInt(scan);  
c = getInt(scan);
```

This is what you probably wanted:

```
a = getInt(scan.nextInt());  
b = getInt(scan.nextInt());  
c = getInt(scan.nextInt());
```

Comment: This gives me another error which occurs in my method:

Error: Cannot invoke hasNextInt() on the primitive type int.

which is in the line:
      while (!input.hasNextInt()){

Comment: @klab102 I use `nextInt()` in my example, not `hasNextInt()`.

Comment: I made that change in the main method, the error that I am receiving is in the method getInt, which is determining if the user input is an integer or not.

Comment: @klab102 I ran the codes but I am not getting the error stated by you. Actually I already answered what you were asking. We won't know what is going on at your side now since you are changing your codes from your side. I can only answer you from your given codes.

Comment: I've edited my original post above with the change, but I'm getting so many compile errors in my method now.  I've only check to see if a number is an integer in a main method before, which is why I am lost as for what I should do here.