# Scanner won't wait to read nextInt() in loop

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I need to read in an integer then display a message if it was not an integer, I need this to loop until only a int is entered. The problem I have with the code below is when it loops it won't wait to read the nextInt, it will just keep looping - printing out the try again message.

```
    do {
        if (reader.hasNextInt()) {
            userX = reader.nextInt();
            isANumberFlag = true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Please enter numbers only, try again: ");
        }
    } while (isANumberFlag == false);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are stuck in the while loop because the index of your reader stays at the same point.
So if you type `"some non numeric gibberish"` the pointer will stay at this point and the program will keep asking you to enter a number. You can solve this  by either moving your index in the else clause:

```java
 Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean isANumberFlag = false;
    int userX = 0;
    do {
      System.out.println("please enter a number: ");

      if (reader.hasNextInt()) {
        userX = reader.nextInt();
        isANumberFlag = true;
      }
      else {
        System.out.println("Please enter numbers only, try again: ");
        reader.next(); //move your index in the else clause
      }
    }
    while (isANumberFlag == false);
    System.out.println(userX);
  }
```

Note this solution will ask you to type something again if you type a word that is partial numeric, for instance: `"notValid5000"`.

However if you type a partial numeric sentence, for instance: `"notValid 5000"` it will say `"Please enter numbers only, try again: "` and directly accept the numeric `5000` part, as an Integer.

Another solution is reading a line as a String and validating that the specific line is a int by using a regular expression:

```java
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean isANumberFlag = false;
    String input;
    int userX = 0;
    do {
      System.out.println("please enter a number: ");
      input = reader.nextLine();

      if (input.matches("\\d+")) {
        userX = Integer.parseInt(input);
        isANumberFlag = true;
      }
      else {
        System.out.printf("you typed %s, which is not allowed \n", input);
        System.out.println("Please enter numbers only, try again: ");
      }
    }
    while (isANumberFlag == false);
    System.out.println(userX);
```

This solution will only accept your input, if the entire line is numeric.

More information regarding int validation with a Scanner can be found on [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912817/how-to-use-scanner-to-accept-only-valid-int-as-input)

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like below.  You need to create 2 Scanner object, first one to get user input, and the second one to verify and get the int.

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean isANumberFlag = false;
    int userX = 0;
    do {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(sc.nextLine());
        if (input.hasNextInt()) {
            userX = input.nextInt();
            isANumberFlag = true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Please enter numbers only, try again: ");
        }
    } while (!isANumberFlag);
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a second scanner to verify the input??

Comment: That second scanner doesn't serve any meaningful purpose.

Answer (score -1):

If the condition for your loop is `!(reader.hasNextInt())` then why would `if (reader.hasNextInt())` even run? Those statements contradict each other. One says it doesn't haven't a value and one says it does. Try changing your if statement's condition to `!(reader.hasNextInt())` or use a Boolean variable to control the loop.