# Check loop if input are all integer

Tags: java, loops, exception

I'm making simple program where the user inputs a class number of a student(cn) and the grade of that student(ngrade). I was trying to add an exception that checks if the input of the cn and ngrade are integers. If not the user will be informed that it is invalid and asks to re enter the details.

problem: i did use while loop to check the inputs throughout the loop. but i'm getting a infinite loop.

CODE:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class trrying {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int ngrade;
        int cn;
        int A = 0, B = 0, C = 0, D = 0, E = 0;
        boolean test = false;
        Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (!test) {
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {

                    System.out.println("Enter class number: ");
                    cn = sn.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter numeric grade: ");
                    ngrade = sn.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Letter Grade: ");

                    if (ngrade >= 90) {
                        A++;
                        System.out.println("A");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("HELLO");
                    }

                    test = true;

                }
                test = false;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("ERROR! ");
                // System.out.println("Enter class number: ");

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Related: [Validating input using java.util.Scanner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059333/validating-input-using-java-util-scanner), [How to use Scanner to accept only valid int as input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912817/how-to-use-scanner-to-accept-only-valid-int-as-input)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

One option to get the behavior you want would be to read in each input as a string, using `Scanner#nextLine()`, and then manually try to parse that input as an integer.  If successful, accept that input and continue with your logic.  If not successful, then catch the exception, and repeat the loop to get another user input.

```
for (int i=0; i <= 2; i++) {
    String line = "";
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Enter class number: ");
        line = sn.nextLine();
        try {
            cn = Integer.parseInt(line);
            break;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Enter class number as an integer only.");
        }
    }
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Enter numeric grade: ");
        line = sn.nextLine();
        try {
             ngrade = Integer.parseInt(line);
             break;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Enter numeric grade as an integer only.");
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Letter Grade: ");

    if (ngrade >= 90) {
        System.out.println("A");
    }        
    else {
         System.out.println("HELLO");
    }

    test = true;
}
```

Comment: Note: I began penning this answer before it was marked as duplicate.  I will leave this answer here so the OP can see one way of solving this problem.

Comment: Please consider adding explanatory text and making it a community wiki

Comment: When you edit the answer, you'll see a checkbox that does just this. It should be fairly easy to find.

Comment: Not the down-voter, but now down-votes won't affect you.