# taking integer input in java

Tags: java, parsing, input

I am actually new to java programming and am finding it difficult to take integer input and storing it in variables...i would like it if someone could tell me how to do it or provide with an example like adding two numbers given by the user..

Comment: Input from where? Program arguments? Console UI? GUI/Swing?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you researched the Scanner class (if you're reading from the console)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's my entry, complete with fairly robust error handling and resource management:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

/**
 * Simple demonstration of a reader
 *
 * @author jasonmp85
 *
 */
public class ReaderClass {

    /**
     * Reads two integers from standard in and prints their sum
     *
     * @param args
     *            unused
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // System.in is standard in. It's an InputStream, which means
        // the methods on it all deal with reading bytes. We want
        // to read characters, so we'll wrap it in an
        // InputStreamReader, which can read characters into a buffer
        InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);

        // but even that's not good enough. BufferedReader will
        // buffer the input so we can read line-by-line, freeing
        // us from manually getting each character and having
        // to deal with things like backspace, etc.
        // It wraps our InputStreamReader
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isReader);
        try {
            System.out.println("Please enter a number:");
            int firstInt = readInt(reader);

            System.out.println("Please enter a second number:");
            int secondInt = readInt(reader);

            // printf uses a format string to print values
            System.out.printf("%d + %d = %d",
                              firstInt, secondInt, firstInt + secondInt);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            // IOException is thrown if a reader error occurs
            System.err.println("An error occurred reading from the reader, "
                               + ioe);

            // exit with a non-zero status to signal failure
            System.exit(-1);
        } finally {
            try {
                // the finally block gives us a place to ensure that
                // we clean up all our resources, namely our reader
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                // but even that might throw an error
                System.err.println("An error occurred closing the reader, "
                                   + ioe);
                System.exit(-1);
            }
        }

    }

    private static int readInt(BufferedReader reader) throws IOException {
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Integer.parseInt turns a string into an int
                return Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                // but it throws an exception if the String doesn't look
                // like any integer it recognizes
                System.out.println("That's not a number! Try again.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is good for learning but as Ash suggested the Scanner class is much more convenient (http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Comment: I'm not sure that an object which has a BNF grammar in its Javadoc header is the most user-friendly thing. Sure it's convenient and powerful for parsing console input, but it's stateful and a lot more complex than explaining how to read a single line and parse it as an int.

Answer (score 5):

[`java.util.Scanner`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) is the best choice for this task.

From the documentation:

> For example, this code allows a user to read a number from System.in:
>
> ```
>  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
>  int i = sc.nextInt();
> ```

Two lines are all that you need to read an `int`. Do not underestimate how powerful `Scanner` is, though. For example, the following code will keep prompting for a number until one is given:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
while (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
    System.out.println("A number, please?");
    sc.next(); // discard next token, which isn't a valid int
}
int num = sc.nextInt();
System.out.println("Thank you! I received " + num);
```

That's all you have to write, and thanks to [`hasNextInt()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29) you won't have to worry about any `Integer.parseInt` and `NumberFormatException` at all.

#### See also

- [Java Tutorials/Essential Classes/Basic I/O/Scanning and Formatting](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/scanfor.html)

#### Related questions

- [How do I keep a scanner from throwing exceptions when the wrong type is entered? (java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496239/how-do-i-keep-a-scanner-from-throwing-exceptions-when-the-wrong-type-is-entered)
- [How to use Scanner to accept only valid int as input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912817/how-to-use-scanner-to-accept-only-valid-int-as-input)

---

#### Other examples

A `Scanner` can use as its source, among other things, a [`java.io.File`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.io.File)), or a plain [`String`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.lang.String)).

Here's an example of using `Scanner` to tokenize a `String` and parse into numbers all at once:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner("1,2,3,4").useDelimiter(",");
int sum = 0;
while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
    sum += sc.nextInt();
}
System.out.println("Sum is " + sum); // prints "Sum is 10"
```

Here's a slightly more advanced use, using regular expressions:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner("OhMyGoodnessHowAreYou?").useDelimiter("(?=[A-Z])");
while (sc.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(sc.next());
} // prints "Oh", "My", "Goodness", "How", "Are", "You?"
```

As you can see, `Scanner` is quite powerful! You should prefer it to [`StringTokenizer`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html), which is now a legacy class.

#### See also

- [Java Tutorials/Essential Classes/Regular expressions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html)
- [regular-expressions.info/Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

#### Related questions

- [Scanner vs. StringTokenizer vs. String.Split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691184/scanner-vs-stringtokenizer-vs-string-split)

Answer (score 3):

you mean input from user

```
   Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");

    int number = s.nextInt();

//process the number
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about those parameters from the console input, or any other `String` parameters, use static [`Integer#parseInt()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) method to transform them to `Integer`.