# Checking if the input value is integer type java

Tags: java, validation, input

I am requesting users input where he needs to write integers. I managed to create validation that checks if the value is higher than needed and so, with this code :

```
int n = sca.nextInt(); 
while (n<=0){
    System.err.println(error_1);
    n = sca.nextInt(); 
}
```

But now how to add check for strings, I found such solution [How do I keep a Scanner from throwing exceptions when the wrong type is entered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496239/how-do-i-keep-a-scanner-from-throwing-exceptions-when-the-wrong-type-is-entered)

That uses `hasNextInt()` before actually reading the input, I tried to put this check inside while loop in the same place with `n<=0` like this

```
while ( (n<=0)||(sca.hasNextInt() )) {
  ....
}
```

But it responded with error that variable `n` is not compatible with that method.
So is there any way to overcome such thing?

Comment: Can we get the exact error message? (and if possible a small, complete example that still shows your problem)

Comment: "variable n is not compatible with that method": I am sure this was not the exact error message. What did you get?

Comment: @Dennis Meng  I am sorry guys, but I can't recreate the error. Is there way to find previus compiling errors ?

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the error at all? If not, then there's not much help any of this is going to be able to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First invocation of `nextInt()` also can result in an exception, if you do not check whether the input is of `int` type.

Hope below will resolve your issue.

```
Scanner sca = new Scanner(System.in);

boolean incorrectInput = true;
int userInput = -1; // initialize as a negative  

while (incorrectInput) {

    if (sca.hasNextInt()) {
        int n = sca.nextInt();
        if (n < 0) {
            System.err.println("error_1");
        } else {
            // do anything else
            userInput = n;
            incorrectInput = false;
        }
    } else {
        sca.next();
    }
}

if (!incorrectInput) {
    System.out.println("UserInput = " + userInput);
}
```

Comment: @Ikamal IT is almost there, just need to resolve that the  program methods that is below this code cannot access to n variable :(But anyway thanks for this

Comment: @Ikamal Is there any ideas, because I tried to change n variable location , but no succes ;(

Comment: @EdgarsRozenfelds Updated the code to allow access to the user input outside the while loop using a new variable named `userInput`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use parseInt and check exception:

```
public boolean parseWithFallback(String text) {
try {
  Integer.parseInt(text);
  return true;
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
 return false;
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to test if there is a next Int before trying to get the next Int.

```
boolean finished = false;
while(!finished){
  while(scan.hasNextInt()){
    int n = sca.nextInt(); 
    if(n <= 0){
      System.out.println("Error: Number smaller 0");
    } else {
      System.out.println("correct!");
      finished = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks great, but Where you got never got an Integer I need to call again input, so many times as needed to user insert correct data.

Comment: put your scanner in an other while loop repeating until your get your correct Integer.

Answer (score 0):

You can request and validate user input as many times as need to do it right.

```
    private int readUserInput(String messageToUser) {
    System.out.print("Enter " + messageToUser);
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean validInput = false;
    int res = 0;
    do {
      try {
        validInput = scan.hasNextInt();
        if (!validInput) {
          throw new NotIntUserInputException();
        }
        res = scan.nextInt();
        if (res < 1) {
          validInput = false;
          throw new NotPositiveIntUserInputException();
        }
      } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print(e.getMessage());
        scan.next();
      }
    } while (!validInput);
    return res;
  }
```

You have to create 2 classes NotIntUserInputException and NotPositiveIntUserInputException that are inheriting Exception class